# Programmatically import Currency Rates in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0.

I want to import all my currency rates programmatically and i want to add x% extra to all available currencies.

```
// Code for Import Currency Rates
$currencyModel = Mage::getModel('directory/currency');
$currencies = $currencyModel->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
$defaultCurrencies = $currencyModel->getConfigBaseCurrencies();
$rates=$currencyModel->getCurrencyRates($defaultCurrencies, $currencies);
$percentage = 1.05;  // x% percentage (Example 5%)
foreach($rates[$baseCurrencyCode] as $CurrencyCode => $value  ) {
    $newValue = $value*$percentage;
    $newValue = round($newValue,4);
    $currencies = array($baseCurrencyCode => array($CurrencyCode => $newValue) );
    Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->saveRates($currencies);  // Update value in DB
}
```

How to Import Currency Rates from Webservicex ?

If i can place this code before the above line of code thats it my goal.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please, add some code samples you wrote so  far

Comment: @Tomasz please have a look into my updated question.

Comment: @Salketer please have a look into my updated question.

Comment: Please have a look in to my new edit. I want some script to import Original Currency Rates from Webservicex.

Comment: You appear to already have the Magento code to save the currency rates. this library might help you to fetch the exchange rate which you can then easily manipulate + x% https://github.com/florianv/swap

Comment: @paj Thanks for your help. Is there anyway to use Magento Default Webservicex for Currency Rates Import.

Comment: this answer should help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12494/manage-currency-rates-dynamically-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

Im am using floatrates.com to get the exchange rates from Euro:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_URL,  'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/eur.xml');
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',));
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$xml_response = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);                

$sxml= new SimpleXMLElement($xml_response);

$rates= array();
foreach($sxml->item as $item) { 
    $rates[(string)$item->targetCurrency] = (1/ str_replace(',','',$item->exchangeRate));
    }
```